# How can I correctly display a list of images from database in asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

My requirement is to get the images from the database and display in front end.In my case i  am using asp.net MVC . Database ir oracle and the data type of the image is blob .The follwing is my code

**Model**

This is the Model for the class and it has two properties `ImageDisplay` and `ImageStream`.

```
public class SelectionModel
{
    public byte[] ImageDsiplay { get; set; }
    public MemoryStream ImageStream { get; set;}
}
```

**Controller Code**

In the controller I'm trying the get the image from he database and assign to the Model.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    SelectionModel sel = new SelectionModel();

    List<SelectionModel> lissel = new List<SelectionModel>();
    byte[] imagedata;

    string sql = "select filecontent from filestore";

    OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(ConStr);
    OracleCommand com = new OracleCommand(sql, con);

    try
    {
        con.Open();

        OracleDataReader dr;

        dr = com.ExecuteReader();

        while (dr.Read())
        {
            imagedata = (byte[])dr[0];

            sel.ImageDsiplay = imagedata;

            var stream = new MemoryStream(sel.ImageDsiplay);

            sel.ImageStream = stream;

            lissel.Add(sel);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // ??
    }

    //Here i am trying to return the list .

    return View(lissel);
}
```

**View Code**

The Following is the view code and it should display the image .

```
@model IEnumerable<GoldForGold.Models.SelectionModel>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>        
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <img  src="@Url.Action("Index", "Selection")" alt="myimage" />
            }
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**ISSUE**

The issue is i am not able to display the images from the database.    Image  is   not displayed.I have tried for quite sometime but not able to figure out the issue

Comment: You keep repeating your intro. You keep repeating your intro. You keep repeating your intro.

Comment: Lol..itsme86 .It was not leting me to post the question .I wanted to me add more content . So sorry about that.. Do you have an solution for the above problem?

Answer (score 1):

Historically, I've used an [IHttpHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihttphandler%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for this sort of thing. Something like this:

```
public class EmployeePhotoHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    public bool IsReusable { get { return false; } }

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        int employeeID;
        if (!int.TryParse(context.Request.QueryString["ID"], out employeeID))
            return;

        EmployeePhoto photo = EmployeeService.GetPhotoByEmployee(EmployeeService.GetEmployeeByID(employeeID));
        if (photo == null || photo.Photo == null)
            return;

        context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
        context.Response.BinaryWrite(photo.Photo);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello itsme86 ..I am trying to work with your solution ..can you please explain as per my quesion because i am just starting with MVC

Comment: I mean to say what are the properties in the model should look like and what is the line of code in the view to render the image .

Answer (score 1):

I use the WebImage class in my controllers for dynamically rendering and resizing image in the DB:

```
[ImageOutputCache(Duration = 18000)]
public void Image(int id)
{
    Image image = ImageDAL.SelectSingle(e => e.ImageId == id); //EF Model

    WebImage webimage = new WebImage(image.Data); //image.Data (byte[])

    //resize, crop etc

    webimage.Write();
}
```

Here is the attribute code for the output caching (otherwise the cache outputs a content type of text/html):

```
    public class ImageOutputCache : OutputCacheAttribute
    {
        public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            base.OnResultExecuting(filterContext);

            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
        }
    }
```